# Google Analytics subspecs not present

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using the `Google Analytics iOS SDK` on a few of the projects I work on. I've been trying to install it on the latest one and have run into the weirdest issue. The issue i'm having is that the libraries and everything builds fine, I have generated a config file for the app I am working on and that looks fine too but as soon as I run the app I get the following message in my console:

```
Attempted to configure [Identity, Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].
2015-07-09 09:02:10.738 [19018:5111252] Successfully configured [].
2015-07-09 09:02:10.738 [19018:5111252] Failed to configure [].
2015-07-09 09:02:10.738 [19018:5111252] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Identity, Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].
```

No matter what I've tried I cannot get Analytics to configure properly :/

Has anyone else run into the problem? I even tried a config file for a different app that was working but that did not work either. Any help would be much appreciated!

I've posted on the Google developer forum here too: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ga-mobile-app-analytics/aqM-SqNqQLo

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: I too got in he same problem.I guess its because of multiple pods downloaded but not used. Did you found any solution?

Comment: No solution yet unfortunately. I actually don't use pods on this project due to the complexity of it's structure (multiple sub projects for white-labeling the app) which causes lots of issues. That said, I have also used Google Analytics without pods on other projects and it works perfectly fine. It's just this one giving me this problem

Comment: I would suggest give it a try with pods.You may get solution. Add project path in podfile(`xcodeproj 'path/to/project.xcodeproj'` ) if you are concerned about workspace.

Comment: I use pods and I have the same issue :/

Comment: I have used Google Analytics with both pods and no pods and have gotten both to work successfully on other projects but cannot for the life of me understand why it does not work for this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK. You can ignore it. For me I used the code below to implement event tracking:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-000000-1"];
NSMutableDictionary *event = [[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:category
                                        action:action
                                         label:nil
                                         value:nil] build];
[tracker send:event];
```

instead of

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
```

Comment: This is for the old SDK :/

Comment: Apologies this was not for the old SDK and the problem was that this line: id<GAITracker> tracker =  [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]; was not working (I think my configuration file was possibly in the wrong place?).

I fixed this by using the above "id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-000000-1"];" code. 

The subspecs not present message can be ignored as the answer says

Answer (score 1):

You should add GoogleService-Info.plist in your app.
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=analytics&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fdevguides%2Fcollection%2Fios%2Fv3%2Fapp%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue%23add%2Dconfig&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Analytics

Your tracking id and app bundle should be included in the plist document. 
Also be sure that IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED TRUE in the document.

Comment: Yes this is there too unfortunately :/

Comment: As well as a TRACKING_ID

Answer (score 0):

gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;  // remove before app release

Tha above line might have been commented.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
Set `IS_ADS_ENABLED` to `NO`, or any other conflicting settings
(`IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED`, `IS_GCM_ENABLED`, `IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED`)
*Note I have not encountered this error with anything besides `IS_ADS_ENABLED`*

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I encountered this same error when trying to use [AdMob for iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#streamlined_using_cocoapods) which looks like it is in beta while also trying to use [Analytics for iOS (version ~> 7.0)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift#get-config). The issue arose for me because the Analytics for iOS uses a `GoogleService-Info.plist` for configuration, where I set `IS_ADS_ENABLED` to `YES`. Changing the value to `NO` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was, that I had folder with `SignIn` framework. I deleted it, then installed from pods.

For example for google sign in:

```
'pod 'Google/SignIn'
```